# upgrade pip fail: "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" was tried

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Command I input: pip install ipython

Output:

```
*Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 880, in _download_http_url
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, filename)
  File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.*
```

I tried the command it provided: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

it showed nothing. After that, I tried "pip install ipython" again the same error popped up.

Comment: Last pip version for Python2 is 20.3. https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support

Comment: You should really move to python3

Comment: Do you have python3 installed too?

Comment: Because the existing program has been developed on python2.7, I have to move on it on this version.

Answer (score 1):

This was the case for me. By typing this command `easy_install -U pip` it worked for me.